# Google Sky Map Geocentric Coordinates

Tags: android

Since Google Sky Map was [open sourced](http://code.google.com/p/stardroid/), I decided I would play around with it and experiment a bit. I have so far worked out that objects like stars, galaxies etc. are positioned using the GeocentricCoordinate class. It's basically just a normalised Vector3. However I have not been able to figure out what kind of coordinate system this is, exactly.

For example, as a test, I tried to draw something with coordinates (0,0,0), but the app just doesn't draw anything. So I tried with (1,0,0) and this appeared at some arbitrary point in space, nowhere near the equator or anything. Different coordinated just give equally arbitrary results.

Hopefully someone has some idea of how this works.

Comment: I always assumed the project used your GPS coordinates, along with sensor data (gravity sensor probably) to produce the mapping of the sky. The gravity sensor produces x,y,z values that could be the vector coordinates you're talking about.

I haven't looked at the source code at all, just suggesting that those coordinates might have something to do with the sensors and not points in space.

Comment: That's right, but what I am confused about is the coordinate system it uses to map objects in the sky. The GPS and sensor values just tell it which part of the sky to show. 

I think what happens is all the objects are 'plotted' in some sort of 3D Cartesian system. Normally, from what I have seen on the internet, the Z-axis is effectively the North pole, and the x-y plane is in the same plane as the equator. This doesn't seem to be true in this case for some reason.

Comment: Astronomical databases are kept in declination and right ascension.  Declination is degrees +north or -south of the equator -- essentially the same as latitude.  Right ascension is the angle west of the Sun's position at the vernal equinox (often measured in hours rather than degrees.)  SkyMap probably determines your position on the Earth plus the orientation of the device, and computes a transformation that converts declination and RA into X,Y coordinates on your screen.  Dunno if this information will help you.

Comment: @EdwardFalk What I've managed so far is reading in a [TLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) from Celestrak and calculating coordinates using predict4java, which all works fine. I can probably find a way to convert predict4java's result to RA/DEC (btw the interwebs say that RA/DEC is fixed, unlike azimuth/elevation because it is effectively latitude/longitude).